# SignalR hub not working with existing tables

Tags: sockets, signalr

In the begining I have given service broker enable status to database on MSSQL 2008. I have two tables with same fields. First one is existing table. Other is created new by me. Hub is not working with first existing table, but works fine with other table which we create new.

Our select statement is basic and we have used only select field like 'select field1,field2 from Table1 where field2=1'.

I am using C#.

What kind of problem can be in this issue, how can we solve?

Answer (score 0):

I have found solution. SignalR wants table scheame name in sql statement. Default scheme name is dbo and our sql or stored procedure include dbo. Like:

'Select field1,field2 from dbo.Table1 where field2=1'.